# What is wrong with my loop code?

Tags: matlab, loops

I wrote a loop code to extract my table files names into a string or an array and meanwhile collect the data into arrays. But I found my code went wrong as only one file was read and repeated in the loop over and over again. I had no idea where my code is wrong and it already took me several hours to look for the problem. Could somebody help me?

```
DataCircle      = dir('*-circle.xls');
MeanAreaCircle  = [];
ColonyNumCircle = [];
PlateNameCircle = [];

for zz = 1:numel(DataCircle)
   basefilenamedata1 = DataCircle(w).name;             % generate the base name
   DataName1         = regexprep(basefilenamedata1,'-circle.xls',''); %replace part of the name and the extension
   PlateNameCircle   = [PlateNameCircle DataName1];    % collect the file name into a string
   T1                = readtable(basefilenamedata1);   % read data in
   MeanAreaCircle    = [MeanAreaCircle mean(T1.area)]; % collect the mean for area
end
```

What I got is like this, which is wrong:

```
>> PlateNameCircle
PlateNameCircle ='IMG_0813IMG_0813IMG_0813IMG_0813IMG_0813IMG_0813IMG_0813IMG_0813IMG_0813IMG_0813'
>>  MeanAreaCircle
MeanAreaCircle =
   1.0e+03 *
    6.4152    6.4152    6.4152    6.4152    6.4152    6.4152    6.4152    6.4152    6.4152    6.4152
```

My input file list:

```
IMG_0809-CC.xls
IMG_0809-circle.xls
IMG_0810-CC.xls
IMG_0810-circle.xls
IMG_0812-CC.xls
IMG_0812-circle.xls
IMG_0813-CC.xls
IMG_0813-circle.xls
```

What I want is a column or a character array or a string like this:

```
PlateNameCircle = 'IMG_0809' 'IMG_0810' 'IMG_0811' 'IMG_0812' 'IMG_0813'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues

**1:** you're using `w` to index the name, instead of `zz`, the loop variable. Apparently, there is a stray variable called `w` in your workspace, equal to 8. That's why you're always reading the same file, regardless of iteration number.

**2:** you're not adding a space in the name:

```
PlateNameCircle = [PlateNameCircle ' ' DataName1];
```

**3:** you're adding the same name on each two consecutive iterations:

```
PlateNameCircle = 'IMG_0809-CC IMG_0809 IMG_0810-CC IMG_0810 ...'
```

### Improvements

1. vectorize and use cell strings
2. preallocate instead of grow-on-the-fly
3. give your variables even-better names (although you already did a pretty good job there already, tbh)

something like:

```
filenames       = {D.name};
PlateNameCircle = regexprep(filenames,'-circle.xls',''); %...doubt this is actually what you want, but it *is* what you've written...

MeanAreaCircle  = zeros(numel(filenames),1);
ColonyNumCircle = [];  % <- not used?

for zz = 1:numel(filenames)   
   T1 = readtable(filenames{zz});      % read data in
   MeanAreaCircle(zz) = mean(T1.area); % collect the mean for area
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the *w* in

```
basefilenamedata1 = DataCircle(w).name;
```

should be *zz* instead. Otherwise you are always looking at the first file in the list.

Comment: Palmface... So I'm so embarrassed... Thank you! :)